# Как задать другой путь к dll?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll

Есть один `.exe` и одна `.dll`.

Когда в `References` указываю путь к `dll`, ставлю `Copy Local = false`.
Так вот `.exe пытаеться` найти `.dll` у себя в `bin\Debug` и выбрасывает `Exception`: "Не удается найти указанный файл."

Мне нужно, чтоб `.exe` тянул `.dll` из её родной директории, а не копировал `.dll` в сою директорию и потом уже тянул её оттуда.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Флаг "Copy Local" к этому не имеет отношения (он только говорит студии, надо ли копировать dll в папку выхода проекта).

Программа пытается загрузить dll сначала из файловой системы (текущая директория, файлы которые попадают в `path` и т.д.), потом из `GAG`. Соответственно, в Вашем случае, Вы скорее всего используете референс напрямую на `dll` и эта `dll` не в `GAG`.

[Подробнее здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7d83bc18.aspx) и [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.privatebinpath(v=vs.90).aspx).

Вам в любом случае надо будет:

**1.** Либо делать `copy local`.

**2.** Либо класть `dll` в системные файлы.

**3.** Либо регистрировать `dll` в `GAG`.

**4.** Либо в самой программе указывать путь к поиску `dll`:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AppendPrivatePath(@"bin\DLLs");
```

Answer (score 9):

Добавлю, что есть и другой путь: создать файл конфигурации `<Program-name>.exe.config` следующего содержания:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="SubPath1;SubPath2" />
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

где `SubPath1`, `SubPath2` - поддиректории каталога с приложением.

Тогда поиск будет происходить изначально в папке приложения, затем в поддиректории <Имя-сборки>\ и после этого в SubPath1, SubPath2.

Comment: а как теперь положить этот файл конфигурации в папку, например, .\config?

Comment: @masuhorukov: никак. Этот файл обязан быть в одном каталоге с .exe (или, кажется, подлинкован к нему как ресурс).