# Свои References, но в подпапке

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть решение с двумя проектами

- `DLL` библиотека
- `WPF` приложение, использующее `DLL` в `References`

При компилировании проекта `WPF`, `DLL` помещается в папку с `EXE`. Однако по независимым от меня причинам необходимо что бы `WPF` приложение искало эту `DLL` в папке `[номер версии]` в папке приложения т.е.:

Если приложение находится в папке `c:\MyProject\project.exe`, а у файла версия `1.0.3.24` значит `DLL` будет находиться в `c:\MyProject\1.0.3.24\MyLibrary.dll`

Вот моё решение:

Свойство `Build Action` у  `App.xaml` установил в `Page`, а в `App.xaml.cs` добавил код.

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main()
{
  try
  {
    //Берём Assembly приложения
    System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    //Берём папку приложения
    string appDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(assembly.Location);
    //Берём версию приложения
    string appVersion = System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location).FileVersion;
    //Вычисляем папку с DLL
    string dllpatch = System.IO.Path.Combine(appDirectory, appVersion);
    //Берем переменную окружения PATH
    string environmentPATH = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
    //Устанавливаем переменную окружения PATH
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", environmentPATH + ";" + dllpatch, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
    //Запускаем приложение
    var application = new App();
    application.InitializeComponent();
    application.Run();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    //Эта строка не срабатывает, Exeption не отлавливается
    System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("MyApplication", ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);
  }
}
```

Однако, при запуске проекта всё нормально, но как только я помещаю `dll` в вышеуказанную папку `try catch` не срабатывает, приложение сваливается в исключение, а лог винды выводиться:

> Приложение: project.exe Версия платформы:
>   v4.0.30319 Описание. Процесс был завершен из-за необработанного
>   исключения. Сведения об исключении: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>   в MyNameSpace.App.Main()

Comment: Может это поможет? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/125015/Как-задать-другой-путь-к-dll/125031#125031

Comment: `AssemblyResolve` пробовали?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуй воспользоваться [`codeBase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4191fzwb(v=vs.110).aspx) в app.config.

```
<configuration>  
   <runtime>  
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  
       <dependentAssembly>  
         <assemblyIdentity name="myAssembly"  
                           publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"  
                           culture="en-us" />  
         <codeBase version="2.0.0.0"  
                   href="http://www.litwareinc.com/myAssembly.dll"/>  
       </dependentAssembly>  
      </assemblyBinding>  
   </runtime>  
</configuration>
```

Еще есть [`<probing>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/823z9h8w(v=vs.110).aspx). В нем можно указывать директории для поиска сборок.

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="bin;bin2\subbin;bin3"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: `<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" publicKeyToken="3750abcc3150b00c" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.9.0.0" newVersion="5.9.0.0" />
   </dependentAssembly>`

Comment: Примерно так, когда версия неизвестна

Comment: Сделал скипт на PostScript, Заменяет строку с папкой в конфиге в зависимости от версии после компиляции. Всё отрабатывает на ура!

Answer (score 2):

#### Событие *AssemblyResolve*

Событие `AssemblyResolve` позволяет вмешаться в процесс и вручную загрузить сборку, которую `CLR` не может найти. Если это событие обрабатывается, то ссылаемые сборки можно распределять по различным местоположениям и по-прежнему
обеспечивать их загрузку.
Внутри обработчика события `AssemblyResolve` производится поиск сборки и ее
загрузка за счет вызова одного из трех статических методов класса `Assembly`: `Load`, `LoadFrom` или `LoadFile`. Эти методы возвращают ссылку на вновь загруженную сборку, и данная ссылка затем возвращается вызывающему коду:

```
static void Main()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += FindAssembly;
    ...
}

static Assembly FindAssembly (object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    string fullyQualifiedName = args.Name;
    Assembly а = Assembly.LoadFrom(...);
    return а;
}
```

PS. Да, это необычное событие - оно имеет возвращаемый тип. При наличии множества обработчиков преимущество получает первый обработчик, который возвратил отличный от `null` объект `Assembly`.

Литература:
Албахари, Джозеф, Албахари, Бен.
С# 6.0. Справочник. Полное описание языка, 6-е изд. : Пер. с англ. - М. : ООО
"И.Д. Вильямс", 2016. - 1040 с.: ил. - Парал. тит. англ.
ISBN 978-5-8459-2087-4 (рус.)

Comment: Я же писал, что даже в Main не заходит, т.е. подписаться на `FindAssembly` не получится. =( данный вариант я тоже пробовал, не получилось.

Comment: По идее, загрузка сборки должна происходить в тот момент, когда она впервые понадобится

Comment: я тоже так думал, однако .Net считает иначе. По крайней мере в WPF